# Check for all package dependencies given a package's source code in R

Tags: r, dependencies, package

I have inherited a R package from a previous colleague.  I am trying to clean up the stated package dependencies in the `DESCRIPTION` file as I have noticed several of them are superfluous.

Since there are over 30 stated dependencies, however, I would rather not have to check each one manually to see if it is actually needed.  I also have a sneaking suspicion that there may be a few dependencies missing from the `DESCRIPTION` as well.

Ideally I would like to be able to analyze the package's source code to automatically determine what dependencies are needed.  I tried to find a tool or package that could do this but haven't had any luck so far.

Comment: If you run R's "check" on it (or perhaps `devtools::check`, R is pretty good about telling you what may be missing from the `NAMESPACE` file ... which can be a good proxy for missing `Imports:` directives in your `DESCRIPTION` file.